Does `gpt-4o-mini-audio` make `gpt-4o-mini` obsolete?
With more and more cool models in the gpt-4o family, I'm having a little trouble understanding how they relate to each other regarding features.
Is the following model still the recommended one to use for text-only chat completion scenarios?

gpt-4o-mini
with the most recent checkpoint gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18

Or do newer models keep all the text-based features like chat completions and structured outputs in place while adding audio capabilities and more recent training data at the exact pricing? For example, this one is dated as much more recent:

gpt-4o-mini-audio
with the most recent checkpoint gpt-4o-mini-audio-preview-2024-12-17

The pricing seems identical (\$0.15 per 1M input tokens, $0.6 per 1M output tokens).
So are there downsides to upgrading to the audio-capable model?
